# Trying to create white list for Content-Security-Policy

Tags: security, http-headers, content-security-policy

I have an iframe that when the user is logged into LinkedIn their browsers works, however when the user is not logged into LinkedIn on their browser I get the following error,

```
Refused to display 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login?session_redirect=%2Foauth%2Fv2%2Flogin-success%3Fapp_id%3D3608601%26auth_type%3DAC%26flow%3D%257B%2522authorizationType%2522%253A%2522OAUTH2_AUTHORIZATION_CODE%2522%252C%2522authFlowName%2522%253A%2522default%2522%252C%2522appId%2522%253A3608601%252C%2522loginHint%2522%253Anull%252C%2522externalBindingKey%2522%253Anull%252C%2522currentSubStage%2522%253A0%252C%2522currentStage%2522%253A%2522LOGIN_SUCCESS%2522%252C%2522redirectUri%2522%253A%2522http%253A%252F%252F192.168.10...2%253Anull%252C%2522currentSubStage%2522%253A0%252C%2522currentStage%2522%253A%2522LOGIN_SUCCESS%2522%252C%2522redirectUri%2522%253A%2522http%253A%252F%252F192.168.10.10%252Fauth%252Fwidget%252Flinkedin%2522%252C%2522codeChallenge%2522%253Anull%252C%2522codeChallengeMethod%2522%253Anull%252C%2522flowHint%2522%253Anull%252C%2522creationTime%2522%253A1528495513789%252C%2522scope%2522%253A%2522r_basicprofile%2Br_emailaddress%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%25227Kk3N5zheQaOr3lC9yRZstUYehubbYjv3YpbNjoY%2522%257D' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'".
```

It looks like this is the result of a violation of Content Security Policy directive.  I added a meta tag in the header of my html code that should have fixed the issue by creating a white list of web sites that are allowed to use, however I am still getting the same error.  Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here is the meta tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'https://www.linkedin.com'
" name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

Comment: The cause for the CSP message cited in the question is the policy that LinkedIn document is served with. That document has a content-security-policy response header with `frame-ancestors 'self'`. That is, that document is saying, Don’t allow other documents it put me into a frame. So your browser is enforcing that policy — and you can’t override that other policy by adding a different policy to the document you’re trying to frame that LinkedIn document in. There’s no way to override it

Comment: @sideshowbarker, thanks I thought so.